# How to fix '$timeout is not a function' error in Jasmine?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I get an TypeError: this.$timeout is not a function on unit testing with Jasmine for angular.js app.

I run a timeout service on my onInit, which gives the error.

Can't find a solution to fix this problem.

The onInit look like:

```
constructor($document, $window, $element, $timeout) {
    this.$document = $document;
    this.$window = $window;
    this.$element = $element;
    this.$timeout = $timeout;
}

$onInit() {
    const elementsList = this.element.children;
    const currentPage = elementsList.findIndex(pageController.findElement) + 1;
    const totalPages = elementsList.length;

    if (totalPages > 1) {
        this.elementsList = elementsList;
        this.currentPage = currentPage;
        this.totalPages = totalPages;
    }

    this.$timeout(() => {
        this.getCurrentPage().style.width = 'auto';
        this.currentStepWidth = this.getCurrentPage().clientWidth;
    });
}
```

and the spec file:

```
describe('$onInit', () => {
    fit('should set currentPage and totalPages', () => {
        let pageCounter = new pageController();
        pageCounter.element = {
            children: [
                { styles: ['pageCurrent'] },
                { styles: ['pageVisited'] }
            ]
        };

        // When
        pageCounter.$onInit();

        // Then
        expect(pageCounter.currentPage).toEqual(1);
        expect(pageCounter.totalSteps).toEqual(2);
    });
});
```

When I run the test, I get the TypeError: this.$timeout is not a function

How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you provide the constructor part of your component and the `configureTestingModule` settings in your test?

Comment: @CastroRoy added the constructor part

Comment: Can you show the `configureTestingModule` in your test?